# Find a formula that describes the given day-price relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, interpolation

Given data:

```
Days    Prices
0   0
1   1000
2   1000
3   1000
4   1600
5   2200
6   2800
7   3400
8   4000
9   4600
10  5200
```

Price is function of day.

I had my formula but always put negative result when I put 0 or 1 or 2 to the variable of days (days = [0, 1, 2], result is always negative). I've kind a stuck. Can you guide me steps by step to get a formula for my data? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried plotting it? What does it look like?

Comment: Yes, it looks flat up to 3 days and then linearly up after 3 days up to to 10 day

Comment: That's also a formula. As good as any you could get. If you want to be algebraic though, you can express it in terms of $f(x) = 1$ when $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise, or $\text{signum}$, though not as nicely.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė what is the requirement to be called a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the price as a function of the day, you notice taht the curve is composed by three different pieces. Then, as explained by the others answers, the following model represents exactly your data.

$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       0 & \textrm{if } x =0\\
       1000 & \textrm{if } x =1 \textrm{ or } x = 2 \textrm{ or } x = 3\\
       600 x - 800 &\textrm  {if } x > 3 & \
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

Comment: Your answer is the most complete. One more question for me please, is this problem solved by linear regression? I kind a confuse how to solve this kind of problem whenever I got this. Well, right now, I can solve it with simple trial-and-error math, how can I search for the formula/answer more elegantly/systematically?

Comment: @user2298766. When you have data, report them as points on a graph. This will allow you to see if a single model can be used or if different models are required depending on the range of the independent variable. Assuming you put some noise in the data you gave, it will be clear that you have three areas and then three models. For the last part, perform classical linear (or polynomial) regression [in the case of your data, since they perfectly align, I just used my brain]. If you want, we can continue discussing these topics. Be sure I am glad to have helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is probably as good as we can get. To generalize to all the days, we can define a piecewise function. Let $f(x)$ be the desired function and $g(x)$ the one you have found. Then

$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       0 & \textrm{if } x =0\\
       1000 & \textrm{if } x =1 \textrm{ or } x = 2 \\
       g(x) & \textrm{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right and really helping